# Delete image from folder in PHP, how to take path?

Tags: php, image, path

i have image in folder
when i trying to delete it by this function

```
function delete_item()
{                      
            $query = 'SELECT logo FROM entity WHERE id='.$_GET['id']; 
            $res = mysql_query( $query );
            $item = mysql_fetch_array( $res );
    $file=basename($item['logo']);
    $op_dir=opendir('./img');
    while($file=readdir($op_dir ))
     {

             if($file != "." && $file != "..") 
             {
               unlink ($op_dir.'/'.$file);
              }
              else {
              echo 'no';
              }
    }
    closedir($op_dir); 
}
```

it take error

```
Warning: unlink(Resource id #8/image.jpg) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in
```

image is located example.com/img/f1.jpeg

in code i use $op_dir=opendir('./img'); 
but get a resource and not the path

So question: how to take link or path to image, not resource ?

Comment: PLease put here path to file, from you listed code, and path where image is located.

Comment: You have a nice SQL Injection spot in your code.

Comment: @michail_w
image is located http://example.com/img/f1.jpeg
in code i use $op_dir=opendir('./img');
but get a resource and not the path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$op_dir` is your directory handle, `$file` is your file-name *that you are overwriting* in your loop. You should use a different name for the directory that you get with `readdir()` and use that instead of the directory handle when you try to delete the file, for example:

```
while($dir=readdir($op_dir ))
{
     if($file != "." && $file != "..") 
     {
       unlink ($dir.'/'.$file);
     }
     else
     {
       echo 'no';
     }
}
```

And you should switch to PDO or mysqli and use prepared statements to avoid sql injection but that is not related to your current problem.